# If previous string was true, return false, else true - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, boolean

So if I wanted to alternate between true and false for the value of a string within function how would I got about doing that? I know it's similar to the title but not sure how to put the first part into actual javascript.

```
function tfAlternate(s) {

}
```

So lets say **s** = *"hello"*

If previous string was true (in this case there was no previous string) return false, else true.

so **s** would be true.

but if **s** = *"goodbye"* now i would want it to be false if it followed the if statement as **s** was previously true.

so how would I actually write that as an if statement?

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you have an input at all if the function always alternates.

Comment: @FelixKing: I don't think the function always alternates. Instead, it returns the boolean inverse of the previous input. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi!**

If I understand you correctly, you need a function which accepts a string as input; and returns the boolean inverse of the previously accepted string. If there is no previous string, act as if the previous string was false, thus making the output true.

I agree with @CD.. and @Felix King. You'd need to track the previous string.

But instead of using a global variable or property on the function itself, I suggest using a closure:

```
var tfAlternate = (function () {
    var previousStr = null;     // False value, for no previous string.
    return function (s) {
        var ans = !previousStr; // Negate previous string. 
        previousStr = s;        // Current string is the next previous string.
        return ans;             // Return negated previous string.
    };
}());
```

Paste the above code in your browser's console; and take it for at test drive:

```
tfAlternate("Hello");   // true,  because !null is true
tfAlternate("goodbye"); // false, because !"Hello" is false
tfAlternate("foo");     // false, because !"goodbye" is false
tfAlternate("");        // false, because !"foo" is false
tfAlternate("bar");     // true,  because !"" is true
tfAlternate("baz");     // false, because !"bar" is false
```

**Hope this helps.**

**PS:** I found this question very interesting. However, it isn't clearly worded. If my interpretation of the question is correct, please tell me so; I'll edit the question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have to keep state between function calls. There are multiple ways to do this. One is to keep the state in a variable:

```
var previous = false;
function tfAlternate() {
  return (previous = !previous);
}
```

Here however, `previous` is accessible outside the function and pollutes the scope. The fact that we use `previous` is more of an implementation of the function. We can keep it "private" by creating a new scope and have the function close over it: We create a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

```
var tfAlternate = (function() { // IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression
  var previous = false;
  return function tfAlternate() { // name is optional, but helps with debugging
    return (previous = !previous);
  };
}());
```

In JavaScript, scope is primarily created by functions, hence we call a function to create scope (the IIFE), define all the private variables inside of it, and return the function that should be callable by other code.